# FileNotFoundError when using py2exe

Tags: python, pyside, py2exe

I have a gui program written in Python 3.9 that uses the PySide6 library. I want to make this into a .exe file using py2exe. However, when I try to open the executable I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 167, in exec_module
  File "PySide6\__init__.pyc", line 123, in <module>
  File "PySide6\__init__.pyc", line 111, in _find_all_qt_modules
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Path not found: 'C:\\Users\\...\\Documents\\gui\\dist\\library.zip\\PySide6'
```

The executable file is generated by the commands in cmd:

```
C:\Users\...\Documents\gui>py setup.py install
```

with setup.py being:

```py
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}},
    windows = [{'script': "main.py"}],
)
```

The file im trying to convert is main.py:

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton


# Subclass QMainWindow to customize your application's main window
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My App")

        button = QPushButton("Press Me!")

        # Set the central widget of the Window.
        self.setCentralWidget(button)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

Another post had a similar problem with the pysvn library, however the solution seems incomplete. [Python - FileNotFoundError for pysvn in calling exe compiled with py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68505970/python-filenotfounderror-for-pysvn-in-calling-exe-compiled-with-py2exe)

Comment: use pyinstaller

Comment: yeah, that works much better. Thank you! @Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure what causes the error nor how to fix it. The comments suggested that I use pyinstaller instead, which indeed fixes the problem.